# Having a problem combining an if statement to run AFTER a .json files data has loaded (if that .json function includes a location.reload element)

Tags: javascript, html, json

My page loads data from a .json file and shows it within the html page. 
there is also a  location.reload element that constantly looks for changed data and updates it if the .json file has been changed. See Code screen 1

```
var previous = null;
var current = null;

setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('thenumber.json', function(data) {

        var text = `The number = ${data.thenumber}<br>
                     Confirmed = : ${data.confirmed}`

        var pass = `${data.thenumber}`

        var conf = `${data.confirmed}`


        $(".mypanel").html(text);

        $(".passRef").html(pass);

        $(".confirmRef").html(conf);


        current = JSON.stringify();            
        if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
            console.log('refresh');
            location.reload();
        }
        previous = current;
    });                       
}, 2000);
```

I also want to add some if statements that should only run after the .json data has populated to the html page, This I got to work (without the reload function included) something like Code screen 2 (for some reason its not working tonight, sigh!).

```
  $(document).ready(() => {
  function whatever() {

  var what = document.getElementById('confirmRef').innerHTML;

  if (what == 'true' ) {

       console.log ("call button should activate");

  } else if (what == 'false' ) {

        console.log ("false confirmation");

  } else {

        console.log ("confirm says something else!");

  }
    $.getJSON('thenumber.json', function(data) {

            var text = `The number = ${data.thenumber}<br>
                         Confirmed = : ${data.confirmed}`
            var pass = `${data.thenumber}`
            var conf = `${data.confirmed}`

            $(".mypanel").html(text);

            $(".passRef").html(pass);

            $(".confirmRef").html(conf);

       })

    .then(() => whatever());
  };

  });
```

The problem is when I try to combine all 3 elements (code screen 3) I'm messing it up somewhere and would appreciate any help in showing me with example code of how the code should look to fix the issue.

```
var previous = null;
var current = null;


$(document).ready(() => {
  function whatever() {

  var what = document.getElementById('confirmRef').innerHTML;

        //console.log (what);

if (what == 'true' ) {

       console.log ("call button should activate");

       //console.log (what);

} else if (what == 'false' ) {

        console.log ("false confirmation");

} else {

        console.log ("confirm says something else!");

  }
  setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON('thenumber.json', function(data) {

            var text = `The number = ${data.thenumber}<br>
                         Confirmed = : ${data.confirmed}`

            var pass = `${data.thenumber}`

            var conf = `${data.confirmed}`


            $(".mypanel").html(text);

            $(".passRef").html(pass);

            $(".confirmRef").html(conf);


            current = JSON.stringify();            
            if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
                console.log('refresh');
                location.reload();
            }
            previous = current;
        });                       
    }, 2000);
    .then(() => whatever());
});
```

Thanks, 
Mark

Comment: why don't you add the whatever() function inside the setInterval right after you set the html fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last code you were wrapping the `whatever()` function around the code and your `then` was part of `setInterval` 
try this

```
var previous = null;
var current = null;


$(document).ready(() => {
  function whatever() {

  var what = document.getElementById('confirmRef').innerHTML;

        //console.log (what);

if (what == 'true' ) {

       console.log ("call button should activate");

       //console.log (what);

} else if (what == 'false' ) {

        console.log ("false confirmation");

} else {

        console.log ("confirm says something else!");

  }
}
  setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON('thenumber.json', function(data) {

            var text = `The number = ${data.thenumber}<br>
                         Confirmed = : ${data.confirmed}`

            var pass = `${data.thenumber}`

            var conf = `${data.confirmed}`


            $(".mypanel").html(text);

            $(".passRef").html(pass);

            $(".confirmRef").html(conf);


            current = JSON.stringify();            
            if (previous && current && previous !== current) {
                console.log('refresh');
                location.reload();
            }
            previous = current;
        })       
        .then(() => whatever());

    }, 2000);
});
```